# C# error as syntax error as ','

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-2.0

the following code is giving me an error;

```
dt = sFunctions.ExecuteQuery(Variables.con, "House_Machinery", "usp_housemachinery_Master_insert" + Id + ",'" + txtItemName.Text + "'," + txthp.Text + "," + txtrate.Text + "," + Variables.sTendercode + "," + Variables.StrResourceHeaderCode);
                sFunctions.setSqldbConnCommand_Close(sSqldbCommand);
```

Incorrect syntax near ','

can anyone give insight on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be because of a missing space after the Stored procedure

```
dt = sFunctions.ExecuteQuery(Variables.con, "House_Machinery", 
  "usp_housemachinery_Master_insert " + Id
```

I would also suggest you consider the following techniques to eliminate this type of problem:

- Use [ADO.NET parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx)
- Or use [string.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d.aspx) for easier reading